pip problems with installing libraries
i have a raspberry pi 5, and every time i try to install a new library (using pip) the following message appears
error: externally-managed-environment

× This environment is externally managed
╰─> To install Python packages system-wide, try apt install
    python3-xyz, where xyz is the package you are trying to
    install.
    
    If you wish to install a non-Debian-packaged Python package,
    create a virtual environment using python3 -m venv path/to/venv.
    Then use path/to/venv/bin/python and path/to/venv/bin/pip. Make
    sure you have python3-full installed.
    
    For more information visit http://rptl.io/venv

note: If you believe this is a mistake, please contact your Python installation or OS distribution provider. You can override this, at the risk of breaking your Python installation or OS, by passing --break-system-packages.
hint: See PEP 668 for the detailed specification.

can someone help please??

What are you ACTUALLY trying to install? Did you read the linked article?

You CAN use pip with venv BUT there is often a better way - depending on what you WANT to install, which you haven't stated.

Nothing to do with Pi5 - this is an issue with python 3.11 (which is well documented and extensively discussed) which requires pip to use a virtual environment.
Example (setting up in directory cp):-
mkdir cp && cd cp && python -m venv --system-site-packages env

Most python packages are available from the distro package manager and that's the better way to install them if you want them available on the system generally; I think per-user packages have been superceded by the venv restriction mentioned by Milliways.
To search for a python package by name:
> apt search python3 gpiozero
Sorting... Done
Full Text Search... Done
python3-gpiozero/stable 1.6.2-1+b1 armhf
  simple interface to everyday GPIO components used with Raspberry Pi (Python 3)

You can then install that w/ sudo apt install python3-gpiozero.
If the package doesn't show up that way, try:
apt search python3 | grep -C 3 -i gpiozero

grep is a text matching tool; see man grep for an explanation of the switches.
